# Does anyone know how to create an image container like this using CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6JN5.jpg)

Hi guys , I would like to contain images like the image above. I am quite sure that I should include the image inside a div container, but I have no idea on how to style the container and image. Other than that, the border has a different color when it's overlapped. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Basically this is the code that I have written, but I don't think that it is the correct way :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: 16px;
  top: 16px;
}

.dimg {
  max-width: 110%;
  max-height: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="dimg" src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/fc350e_e38e21e547204e4b83ff18afcab7f300.jpg">
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post relevant code to show what you have already tried, in order for us to help you fix it :)

Comment: opps sorry I will submit the code now because I am quite new to here ><

Answer (score 0):

This should be good starting point:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  height:160px;
  
}

.img-container {
flex:1;
  position: relative;
  left: -16px;
  top: -16px;
  height: calc(100% + 32px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.caption{
flex:1;
}
.dimg {
  max-width: 110%;

  position: relative;
width:100%;
  
}
.border2 {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height:160px;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="dimg" src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/fc350e_e38e21e547204e4b83ff18afcab7f300.jpg">
 <div class="border2"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</div>
```